# spark-cassandra-connector how the read work

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a question about this connector. If my Spark cluster and my Cassandra cluster are not on the same cluster, how does the READ work? Does Spark bring the entire Cassandra table into its own cluster and rearrange it into Spark partition?

Answer (score 0):

`push down operations` are available between `spark` and `cassandra`as long as you filter early, cassandra will conduct all filters so that you ship over network already filtered data, have a read: [tips cassandra-spark](https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/2016/03/31/cassandra-connector-for-spark-5-tips-for-success/)